# Possible to automatically fold POD in Comma IDE?

Tags: raku, ideavim, commaide

I'm using the paid version of the Comma IDE. I'd like to be able to automatically fold the POD. I'm usig the ideavim plugin but that doesn't seem to offer a solution. I also tried to use the "surround with" feature (option-ctrl-t) per the instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html but that doesn't seem to work with Comma.

Best I could do is to select the pod section, right click, select "Folding" and then "Fold selection." Though this works, it's less than ideal because it's not automatic and they folds easily pop open when you the cursor down through the fold using the 'j' or 'k' keys when moving through the file with ideavim.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements that can be code-folded in IntelliJ platform language supports is [implemented as part of the language support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/folding-builder.html). Comma has a feedback application for subscribers to request features; the best option is probably to request that Pod blocks be added to the set of foldable elements there.

**Update:** Pod folding was implemented in Comma 2023.04.